# Maven2_Builder vs. Maven Project Builder

Tags: maven-2, m2e

I inherited a project that relies on [Maven 2](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2005/jw-1205-maven.html) to build it. Via project's `Properties` >  `Builders` I can see that it has **two** builders, in this order:

1. Maven2_Builder
2. Maven Project Builder

I thought that there should be only one Maven builder...

1. Why two?
2. What the relation between the two?
3. Using the `m2e` plugin, I can clean the project at any given time via the project's context menu `Run As` > `6 Maven Clean`. Does this mean Eclipse's `Project` > `Clean...` is no longer relevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using Eclipse with M2E. These days that works very well.

Before one would run

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

Which would generate the typical Eclipse configuration files.

These days, just use the Eclipse **Import as Maven Project** and all necessary files are created.

Comment: Amazing. This question was asked almost 3 years ago... +1 for the persistence.